# PDO Int placeholders getting quotes around them

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So the following code has been bugging me a bit:

```
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE account=? AND NOT deleted LIMIT ?, 4");
    $stm->execute($user, ($request-1)*4);
```

Whenever I execute this query it returns this error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', 4' at line 1'
```

Upon looking it up it seems that using the ? placeholders automatically puts quotes around it unless you specify with a bindParam. Is there any way to fix this without having to use the bingparam function?

Comment: You can also [turn emulation mode off](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Does that have any side-effects?

Comment: @lemondrop If you ever need PDO to access a different type of DB, it will cause the queries to fail then, however MySQL will be able to sort most of them out.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok I won't be using anything really outside the range of this code I posted so I am sure it will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue and why the `limit` should not really be used with bound parameters.  However, you can overcome this by binding the parameter individually and naming it an int.

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE account=? AND NOT deleted LIMIT ?, 4");
$stm->bindValue(1, $user);
$stm->bindValue(2, ($request-1)*4), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();
```

If you read [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it is caused because binding on the execute causes all parameters to be bound as strings.

As [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) pointed out, you can disable emulation mode and let MySQL sort out the placeholders by itself, though this may not work with all DB drivers (though will with MySQL) by:

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Or you can do an `intval` or type-cast to an int and put it directly within your statement if you'd prefer to do it that way.